# Is it possible to stack two or more materials with transparency for textures?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a model I want the "base" material to be Blue, and I want to apply a material with an image texture to some selected faces only. The image I want to apply has transparency, and I'd like that transparency to show through to the other (base/blue) material. I've had no luck with mixing a transparency shader using the alpha channel as the factor. I'm doubting whether its possible this way. If it's not possible, how should I go about doing this instead?
I wanted to use the material node, but that doesn't seem to be in blender any more.
Thanks in advance :)

[image: Whole scenario] 
[image: Eye mask with transparency showing as black]
My mask image:
[White mask with transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReZW4.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Answer (score 0):

In the material tab, go to Settings and change the Blend Mode from Opaque to Alpha Blend or other related Aplha options

Comment: That makes the texture actually transparent, as opposed to blue like I'm looking for. You end up seeing inside his skull around those edges. The other blend mode settings have similar unwanted effects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having here is that the separate material is acting as you want it to. It is making the faces that use the second material transparent and thereby looking through those faces. Those faces are not associated with the base/blue and therefore are not blue. If you want the transparent areas to be blue then I'd recommend one of the following:

1. Make these selected faces a new object that sit on top of the face (duplicate, separate, move slightly). That way you have your entire head with only `Skin`, and the new object with only `Eyes white mask`.
2. Instead of `Transparent BSDF` in your `Mix Shader` you make it the same material setup as your `Skin`.